# Call BOT listening URL from Ajax function Web method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, botframework

I created an web application with submit button. When the user clicks on this button, there will be Ajax call invoked to communicate the BOT. I used following code for Ajax function

```html
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSend").click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "GroupChat.aspx/GetData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("success!");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);  
                    }
                });
           
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And I used following code to communicate BOT from the web method

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static async Task GetData()
{
    Task<TokenResponse> response = GetTokenAsync();
    response.Wait();
    string token = response.Result.access_token;
    List<BOTConstants> lstConstants = new List<BOTConstants>();

    lstConstants.Add(new BOTConstants
    {
        text = "test message",
        channelId = "webApp",
        serviceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/",
        textFormat = "plain",
        type = "message"
    });

    string json = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(lstConstants);

    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mybot.azurewebsites.net");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       
        var result = await client.PostAsync("https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages", data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
    }
}
```

But, `var result = await client.PostAsync("https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages", data).ConfigureAwait(false);` is always returns Bad request.

Can anybody help me on this to resolve this issue, Please correct me if any mistakes in the above code.

Comment: Where did you get that C# code from? Can you link to any samples or documentation you've followed? Is your bot's api/messages endpoint designed to receive an array of bot constants objects instead of an activity? Can you post the relevant code from your bot?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the direct line API instead of posting directly to your "api/messages" endpoint.

Based on Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), below should be the steps. For the same end-user, you should cache the token and conversation id, so your conversation can continue properly in a multi-turn dialog.

1. Start a conversation.

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations
Authorization: Bearer SECRET

//Response
{
  "conversationId": "abc123",
  "token": "RCurR_XV9ZA.cwA.BKA.iaJrC8xpy8qbOF5xnR2vtCX7CZj0LdjAPGfiCpg4Fv0y8qbOF5xPGfiCpg4Fv0y8qqbOF5x8qbOF5xn",
  "expires_in": 1800,
  "streamUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/abc123/stream?t=RCurR_XV9ZA.cwA..."
}
```

2. After you get the conversation id e.g. "abc123", you can start posting your message to this conversation.

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/abc123/activities
Authorization: Bearer RCurR_XV9ZA.cwA.BKA.iaJrC8xpy8qbOF5xnR2vtCX7CZj0LdjAPGfiCpg4Fv0
Content-Type: application/json
[other headers]

//Request body
{
    "locale": "en-EN",
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
}
```